# Better way of updating/creating model data through local script

Tags: python, django

I have a python web scraping script that updates/creates Django model instances in Production from my local machine.

The reason I'm doing this way and not using something like celery is because I run multiple asynchronous requests and do not want the server costs to raise.

Currently I do this through

```py
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

# import whatever model... 


# Scraping logic...
```

I know this is not a good way, but is there any better way to do it?